# String concat on MS SQL for a group of rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

Lets say I have 2 tables:

1 with users
and another one which keeps record of which users used what codes.

```
Users
-----
Id, Name
1, 'John'
2, 'Doe'

Codes
------
Id, UserId, code
1, 1, 145
2, 1, 187
3, 2, 251
```

Now I want to pull a query that results he following

```
Name, UsedCodes
'John', '145,187'
'Doe', '251'
```

How can this be done with a query or stored procedure?

Comment: Which DB server are you using? Using MySql would make this VERY simple, but a bit more complicated in MS SQL.

Comment: consider that this may not be the optimal format for the resulting data. it may be more efficient to have redundant items in the `Name` column, and have 1 row per user-usedcode.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<strike>Since you haven't specified the DB I'm giving you two options:</strike>

### MySql

With MySql you should simply use `GROUP_CONCAT()` aggregate function.

### Microsoft SQL Server 2005+

Obviously the **fastest way** (no cursors, no coalesce...) of getting the same result on MS DB is by using `FOR XML PATH('')` that simply omits XML elements.

```
SELECT
    u.Name,
    c1.UserId,
    (
        SELECT c2.Code + ','
        FROM Codes c2
        WHERE c2.UserId = c1.UserId
        ORDER BY c2.code
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ) as Codes
FROM Codes c1
    JOIN Users u
    ON (u.Id = c1.UserId)
GROUP BY c1.UserId, u.Name
```

### Other alternatives

Read [this article](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/), that explains all the possible ways of achieving this goal.

Comment: Very useful referenced article.  Be interesting to run tests to see which is the optimal solution.  The SQL/.NET CLR function version seems the cleanest (if you're allowed to compile your own functions into the instance of SQL code is running on)

Comment: Thanks for the article. The FOR XML PATH('') trick worked fine :)

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server as a really quick and dirty you could use a SQL function and a cursor.  I would not really recommend this for high usage and I'll be really embarassed when someone points out a much easier example that doesn't need a function let alone a cursor.

```
SELECT
 t1.Name,
 StringDelimitCodes(t1.ID) as 'UsedCodes'
FROM
 users t1
```

And the function would be something like

```
function StringDelimitCodes(@ID INT) VARCHAR(255)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE CURSOR myCur
   AS SELECT Code FROM Codes WHERE ID UserID = @ID
  OPEN myCur
  DECLARE @string VARCHAR(255)
  FETCH @MyCode = Code FROM myCur
  WHILE @@FetchStatus ==0  
  BEGIN
    IF(@string <> '') 
    BEGIN
      SELECT @String = @String + ','
    END
      SELECT @String = @String + CAST(@CODE AS VARCHAR(10))
    FETCH @MyCode = Code FROM myCur
  END
  CLOSE myCur
  DEALLOCATE myCUR
  RETURN @string 
END
```

EDIT: Sorry for any SQL Syntax errors, don't have SQL installed here to validate, etc. so done from memory.