# SQL breakup string for use with WHERE IN

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-in

I have a table in SQL Server with a column that stores a series of characters. I would like to be able to send a series of characters to a stored procedure and use it for the `WHERE IN`. Example below

```
ID | series
---+-------
 1 | U
 2 | B
 3 | R
 4 | UB
 5 | BR
```

I would like a return as follows:

```
Parameter | Return IDs
----------+------------
 U        | 1
 R        | 3
 U, R     | 1, 3
```

I can format the parameter any way, UR or U, R or whatever. I could break this up in application and call the procedure N times but I would rather not so that I can use an order by in the query.

Comment: SQL Server can accept table types as SPROC parameters - the SPROC can then take advantage of JOINs and other RA/SET operations. It would also be 'more SQL' and easier to expect the output itself to be normalized. For example, calling with the set `{(U),(R)}` (specified as table type) would yield `({R,3},{U,1})` (two normalized rows). The application can then turn the result in the appropriate output format for its own purposes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476186/string-concat-on-ms-sql-for-a-group-of-rows is related for "stuffing" into non-normalized output (which I still advise against). Also one could write a UDF aggregate function. IIRC, SQL Server 2016 has such an aggregate, although it is not coming to mind..

Comment: A table valued parameter is the way to go, if your application is written in a language that supports it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way if you **can not** use a table valued parameter.

```
declare @table table (ID int, series varchar(16))
insert into @table
values
(1,'U'),
(2,'B'),
(3,'R'),
(4,'UB'),
(5,'BR')


declare @input varchar(4000) = 'U,R'

select
    t.*
from @table t
cross apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@input,',') x 
where
x.Item = t.series
```

**OR without Cross Apply**

```
;with cte as
(select * 
from dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@input,',') x )

select
    t.*
from @table t
inner join cte on Item = t.series
```

**[Here is the function](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) which has proven to be a fast method of splitting strings:**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K] (@pString VARCHAR(8000), @pDelimiter CHAR(1))
--WARNING!!! DO NOT USE MAX DATA-TYPES HERE!  IT WILL KILL PERFORMANCE!

RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
RETURN

/* "Inline" CTE Driven "Tally Table" produces values from 1 up to 10,000...
enough to cover VARCHAR(8000)*/

  WITH E1(N) AS (
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
                ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
 cteTally(N) AS (--==== This provides the "base" CTE and limits the number of rows right up front
                     -- for both a performance gain and prevention of accidental "overruns"
                 SELECT TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@pString),0)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
                ),
cteStart(N1) AS (--==== This returns N+1 (starting position of each "element" just once for each delimiter)
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t WHERE SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) = @pDelimiter
                ),
cteLen(N1,L1) AS(--==== Return start and length (for use in substring)
                 SELECT s.N1,
                        ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@pDelimiter,@pString,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000)
                   FROM cteStart s
                )
--===== Do the actual split. The ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the length for the final element when no delimiter is found.
 SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY l.N1),
        Item       = SUBSTRING(@pString, l.N1, l.L1)
   FROM cteLen l
;
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

On way to achieve this is to pass in a delimited string and then create a function to take in your parameter, splits out the values and returns a table value. Then all you need to do is create a stored procedure similar to.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProc
(
    @MyParameter NVARCHAR(3000)
)
AS

SELECT 
    ID,
    Series
FROM
    MyTable
WHERE
    Series IN (SELECT ID FROM dbo.MyFunctionToSplitDelimitedString(@MyParameter,',')
```